# How to download from Amazon cloud to Kindle desktop?

Tags: kindle, ebook-management, kindle-app, send-to-kindle, download

For Kindle itself and Kindle for Android/iOS you can always see what documents you have in your library, and download them when necessary, even if you have already deleted them locally. All the documents I ever sent using "Send to Kindle" are there. However I don't see the option to download those documents on Kindle for OS X. You only seem to be able to download the books that you've bought plus the documents you have locally. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on a listing you get the option to download.

[image]

[image]